# Pattern match check

Tags: javascript, regex

How to search for `"completed"` in string `"test1|completed"`

Is there any reular expression which I can used to slove this problem. I used spilt function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need RegEx here. Simply use [`String.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) function, like this

```
"test1|completed".indexOf("completed") !== -1
```

The `indexOf` function will return the starting index of the string being searched in the original string. If not found, it returns `-1`. So, if the result of `indexOf` is not equal to `-1`, then the string being searched is there in the original string.

**Note:** In the next version of JavaScript (ECMAScript 6), there will be a function called [`contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains) in the String objects and you can use them like this

```
var str = "To be, or not to be, that is the question.";

console.log(str.contains("To be"));       // true
console.log(str.contains("question"));    // true
console.log(str.contains("nonexistent")); // false
console.log(str.contains("To be", 1));    // false
console.log(str.contains("TO BE"));       // false
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ('test1|completed'.indexOf('completed') !== -1) console.log('found')
```

indexOf will return -1 when the string is not found. It's faster and easier than regex, but if you want:

```
if ('test1|completed'.match(/completed/)) console.log('found')
```

See also: [How to check whether a string contains a substring in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-can-i-check-if-one-string-contains-another-substring-in-javascript)

Comment: Don't abuse `alert` like a debugging tool

Comment: @RUJordan What? For example code?

Comment: Yup. Good practice should be practiced even if it seems trivial, like an example

Answer (score 0):

```
/completed/
```

will serve your purpose

```
var str = "test1|completed";
var res = /completed/.test(str);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: @bjb568 i have tried this code in my firebug console, how can you simply downvote without any reason. please check your code first.

Comment: Oh, whoops. It was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

you can alert this and see that it will return the matched string
If not matched it will return null.

```
alert("test1|completed".match("completed"));
```